# iOS: Intercept certain numbers when dialed and start own app

Tags: ios, phone-call

**Usecase:** 
my hotline has phone number 0815/111222333
user starts up dialer and dials that number
instead of calling my app starts up to offer him
service.

I did it on Android, though I am pretty sure this won't be allowed in iOS. 
But I didn't find that explicit statement. I am just looking for confirmation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is most likely not possible on iOS. Event if it was I noted that there is a patent on this.